# How to connect to mysql docker container via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I have managed to create two containers, One for PHP-admin and one for mysql while experimenting with docker-compose.

I am able to connect to the mysql container via mysql workbench but when I try to do the same via php I am getting errors.

My docker-compose:

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SomeRootPassword1!
      MYSQL_USER: someuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Password1!
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testingDb
    volumes:
      - ./dbScript/create_Script2.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_Script2.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: dev_pma
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3308
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8183:80
volumes:
  db_data:
```

When visiting `http://localhost:8183/`:

[image]

I also tried `localhost:3307` as the server name but same result.

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT:
Im new to docker and assume things were correct since I got no erros but this is the message I get when running docker-compse up:

```
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26 22:48:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26 22:48:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26 22:48:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.475118Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 1
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.485772Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.696157Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.833797Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.905493Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.905743Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.910793Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1       | 2020-08-26T22:48:58.936528Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
dev_pma       | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.144.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
dev_pma       | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.144.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
dev_pma       | [Wed Aug 26 22:48:59.408472 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
dev_pma       | [Wed Aug 26 22:48:59.408505 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Not sure if this means anything but thought I would add it to see if anything might be wrong.

Comment: use `mysql:3307`

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but the result is the same. I will update the question with more info maybe you or someone else can spot something I have missed.

Comment: ok then try `mysql:3306`, host is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service name resolves to the IP of DB container.
The port exposed by the container is 3306.

Use `mysql` (the name of the DB service).
Use `3306`(the port on which the DB container is listening instead of the port on which you are publishing on the host)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The other answer also made sense, hence the container names are also resolved, but for some reason it was down-voted and the owner deleted...

Comment: This worked. Kind of makes sense after the fact as always. In regards to the other answer I tried it and it did not work. Cheers

Comment: I guess you tried with `3307`. Can't check what was wrong there, since it's gone.

Comment: No, I just used the container name which the answer said I should. Might actually try it with the container name.

Comment: OK, doesn't matter now. Glad it worked. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: A bit off-topic but I have to ask. How do you make your phpAdmin with black background? lols

Comment: @ThunD3eR, DarkReader extension for Chrome or Mozilla. Hacks the CSS of all sites. Awesome for working during night :))

Answer (score 1):

If you are running phpmyadmin and mysql as a container then add only mysql container ip in server_name column.

Don't include mysql container or host port.

subhash sautiyal